# react-router 2.0 doesn't route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have this simple code that doesn't work. I took it from the react-router project page and modified slightly for it to look a bit better.

**Setup**

I have several very simple react components:

```
var IndexPage = React.createClass({
    render(){
        return (<h1>Index Page</h1>);
    }
});
var AboutPage = React.createClass({
    render(){
        return (<h1>About page</h1>);
    }
});
var NotFoundPage = React.createClass({
    render(){
        return (<h1>Not found page</h1>);
    }
});
```

Also I have made a setup of react router:

```
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var BrowserHistory = ReactRouter.browserHistory;
var Render = ReactDOM.render;
```

And that's how I use react router 2.0.

```
Render((
  <Router history={BrowserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={IndexPage}>
      <Route path="about" component={AboutPage}/>
      <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.body)
```

I use BrowserHistory (not HashHistory) to avoid hash in urls.

My server is raised under IIS 10 (Windows 10) on 8080 port.

**Problem**

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

goes to IndexPage component. This is correct.

```
http://localhost:8080/about
```

goes to IIS 404 error page. Routing doesn't work in this case

```
http://localhost:8080/ttt
```

goes to IIS 404 error page again.

So the router doesn't see this nested paths that go after /. And it doesn't even care about whether they are correct or not.

What can cause such a strange behavior?

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

I've found out that the next string solves the problem with a client routing:

```
{this.props.children}
```

This is the fixed code:

```
var IndexPage = React.createClass({
    render(){

        console.log('index page render');

        return (<div>
                    <h1>Index Page</h1>
                    <Link to={ '/about' }>about</Link>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>);
    }
});
```

Comment: Try http://localhost:8080/#/about

Comment: http://localhost:8080/#about leads to IndexPage

Comment: And i mentioned that I disabled hashes by using BrowserHistory instead of  HashHistory

Comment: I have the same setup, both server-wise and using {this.props.children}, but I get the IIS 404 instead of my custom 404. Works when running on webpack-dev-server.

Comment: I don't use backend yet because it is not so important at the moment. I use client routing. I can send you a fully working very simple example if you want.

Comment: and the most marvelous thing is that hash routing works if you enter an url into the url bar of a browser. Browser routing doesn't allow that. It only works through internal links with the Link tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React-router is a client-side routing solution(also works in server side, but it seems you are using .Net as the server side handler).

You can try this(`Link` from `React-Router`):

```
    <Link to={ pathname: 'about' }>
      about
    </Link>
```

Put it in the index page's component, and click the link, the react-router will work.

Update:
`{this.props.children}` ref to the inner component(`AboutPage`, `NotFoundPage`).
If you change code to that:

`<Route path="/" component={IndexPage} />
    <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage}/>
    <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage}/>`

It will works.(remove the `{this.props.children}` in IndexPage if there is no nesting routes).

Comment: I've tried your approach. I don't know why but your code didn't work. Babel couldn't understand it. And I fixed it with the next version: `<Link to={ 'about' }>
      about
     </Link>`

Comment: This code sets an url to: `http://localhost:8080/about` but IndexComponent is loaded instead of AboutComponent. Strange.

Comment: I have found a solution! But I still can't understand why it solves my problem.

Comment: As well as add a Link I should add the next string after it: `{this.props.children}`. And the Index component starts to work as it should. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Is your server configured to map all application-paths to your index.html? You should never get a IIS 404 if your server would map all path to your index file, as it always would deliver this one.

Comment: I don't think that it is related to IIS settings. Because I downloaded react-router examples from the site and they work fine. Now I am digging them to resolve the problem I have.

Comment: Okay, that was my only guess. Normally all examples from react-router run with node.js express server with url rewrite activated. So its not intended to run in IIS directly without setting up the server. Just saying ;)

Comment: I didn't want to be offensive or something ) Thank you!

Comment: I recommend anyone who are new to reactjs or react-router to follow this egghead tutorial. Very crisp and teaches you modular coding with a clean explanation.
https://egghead.io/lessons/react-building-a-react-js-app-basic-routing-with-react-router

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue linking directly to URLs by adding `--history-api-fallback` to my **webpack-dev-server** command.

Setting this flag prompts **webpack-dev-server** to serve the index page instead of 404. The index page will then route correctly on the client side.